Geometry Nodes : how can I delete a single spline in a curve object?
I thought it would be easy to delete a spline given its index in a curve object, but it's not :)
I'm on Blender 4.3 and this is what I have so far - i'm trying to delete the spline with index "2".

It does nothing.
If I change the B value to 0, every spline is deleted.
What don't I get ?

Works fine on my end.
You are supposed to use the Index from Geometry > Read > Index node.
The Socket Spline Parameter > Index will give you the index of a control point at each spline.


This index is the index of the point on the current spline. If you have multiple curves in the object, then the point index go up along the curve, then restart from 0 for the next curve, and so on.
From the manual about Spline Parameter > Index :

Each control point’s index on its spline. This is different from the output of the index node, which also counts the control points in all previous splines.

You can use the Curve Info > Curve Index instead. You'll get the index of the splines as you are expecting.
Another solution is presented by Duarte Farrajota Ramos. I'd say his answer is cleaner and simpler.

Curve Info: Curve Index you would use if for some reason you were deleting points (for example you want to delete both one entire spline and also some point(s) on other splines in one go).
